# Can I pass a variable between two private functions in different modules?

Tags: vba

I have two private functions in two different modules. These two functions should share a common variable. How should I go about programming this?

The current code is this:

```
Private function TestFunction1 (ByVal traffic as string) As Boolean
'snippet from the code
dim amount as string
amount = inputbox("Fill in amount")
end function
```

---

```
Private Function TestFunction2 (ByVal layout as string) as Boolean
'snippet from the code
dim result as string
result = "the amount is: " & amount
end function
```

I know this is not a correct function but it's just a part of the code. I cannot share the entire code because of business regulations.
How should I go about passing the amount to the other function in another module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that's doable by declaring the `amount` variable as Public:

```
Public amount As Long 'not sure why you declared it as a string, as it seems to be a number

Private function TestFunction1 (ByVal traffic as string) As Boolean
    'snippet from the code
    amount = inputbox("Fill in amount")
End Function
```

Comment: How should I call it in TestFunction2 ? It's in another module

Comment: Have to be careful about the downside of having public variables (have to check they've been set in the first place), but otherwise this is one way to do it.

Comment: The same as you do now. It's optional to specify the module, like `Module1.amount`